# Android Studio Kotlin editText does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

In my Kotlin android project (which should be a ToDo List application when finished), I added an editText to a pop up Window. At first, the keyboard didn't even open up. Then I added this piece of code to the Main Activity (which is called ToDo):

```
val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as 
InputMethodManager
imm!!.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
```

Now, the soft keyboard opens up, but When I type, no text enters into the editText. I tried adding requestFocus
 to the editText in the popup xml, which didnt work.

I tried it on both an emulator and a real phone. Other solutions here on similar questions didnt work. When replying, please keep in mind that I need the solution in Kotlin. Please help me getting the editText to work. Thanks. Here's my Activity code:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)



    fab.setOnClickListener {

        val inflater: LayoutInflater = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todopopup, null)

        val popupWindow = PopupWindow(
                view, 
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) 




        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(coordinatorLayout)
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(
                coordinatorLayout, 
                Gravity.CENTER, 
                0, 
                0 
        )

        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm!!.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)



        val cancelbutton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.cancelbutton)
        cancelbutton.setOnClickListener {
            popupWindow.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

here's my activity layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ToDo">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/content_to_do"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/fab"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:elevation="4dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

here's my pop up window xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:elevation="16dp"
>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="384dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"


/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addtodobutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add ToDo"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="cancel"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/addtodobutton"

    android:background="#FFFFFF"

/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text=" Add a ToDo"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm new to android development, so please explain your answers in a way that's easy to understand. I just want the editText to work. Maybe the problem has something to do with the fact that the editText is in a popup window? I hope that  the code shows properly here. Thanks for answering in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines at the end of FAB's click listener block.

```
popupWindow.isFocusable = true
popupWindow.update() // This line updates the state of the popup window.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. The keyboard still opens up as before, but I still can't type (The keyboard gives feedback on my typing, like showing what character I last pressed, or showing 'ä' when long pressing 'a'. But still, nothing appears in the editText. I also tried clicking on the window and the editText before typing.